Normal form for a pair of matrices.
Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices of complex numbers such that $AB-BA=A$. By Lie's Theorem, there exist a choice of basis such that $A$ and $B$ can be put simultaneously in upper triangular form. We also know that $A$ can be put in its Jordan normal form (with the above-the-diagonal convention).
Q: Is it true that we can do both at the same time: put $B$ in upper triangular form and $A$ in Jordan normal form?
This is trivial when $A$ is a single Jordan block as any $B$ satisfying the equation must be upper triangular.
Thank you

I don't think that it is true. On the other hand, by Sylvester's matrix equation, we know that the matrix equation $XA − AX = X$ has a nonzero solution if and only if $A$ and $A − E$ have a common eigenvalue.

@DietrichBurde Thanks for the comment.
